# Least cost path algorithm in SAGA?

Tags: saga, algorithm, cost-path, dijkstra

I'm very new to this topic.

I have to calculate the least cost path between two points for a school project and found this tutorial: https://dges.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Cost_Path_Analysis_of_Mars_using_SAGA. That's why I also want to use SAGA. But the wikipedia page of Cost distance analysis also talks about different algorithms used for least cost path analysis. One of the more popular algorithms seems to be Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Now I wonder, which algorithm does SAGA use to calculate the least cost path between two points?